# Express Validator .isLength and isEmail is not working

Tags: mongodb, express, express-validator

```js
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  body("name").isLength({ min: 3 }); // Validate name length
  body("email").isEmail(); // Validate email format
  body("password").isLength({ min: 8 }); // Validate password length

  const errors = validationResult(req); // Check for validation errors

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    // Handle errors if present
    res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  } else {
    // No errors, process request
    res.end("received"); // Currently just sends a message
    // Uncomment and customize below to actually create a user:
    // const user = User(req.body);
    // user.save();
    // res.send("User created successfully!");
  }
});
```

the code doesn't work as intended it doesn't give any error even if i give an empty req

Comment: Provide more context to the code. What is the error message you are getting? What is the desired output and does this body function do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the validation middleware checks before the route handler callback [as per the docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/guides/getting-started#handling-validation-errors) like so:

```js
router.post("/", 
    body("name").isLength({ min: 3 }),
    body("email").isEmail(),
    body("password").isLength({ min: 8 }),
    (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req); // Check for validation errors
    
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            // Handle errors if present
            res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        } else {
            // No errors, process request
            res.end("received"); // Currently just sends a message
            // Uncomment and customize below to actually create a user:
            // const user = User(req.body);
            // user.save();
            // res.send("User created successfully!");
        }
});
```